# How to get back column names from indices in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe,

from that I converted to ndarray,

```
X = df.iloc[:].values
```

then I did the feature selection which gives me some columns [3,45,67,89,101,145,...]

as there are many columns may I know how to get back the corresponding column names in the dataframe

The reverse I can do using below code

```
cols = ['Amount','Savings_Amount','Loan_Term']
[df.columns.get_loc(c) for c in cols if c in df]
```

But I need to find names from the indices.

Comment: Have you tried something like `df.columns[[3,45,67,89,101,145]]`? Note the two brackets each

Comment: `df.columns` returns just an array. `df.columns[[3,45,67,89,101,145,...]]` will give a an array with the names. You can use the `to_list()` method if you need them as list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just pass the index to the column index

```py
names = df.columns[ix].values
```

where `ix` is your indexes vector

Answer (score 1):

```
cols = ['Amount','Savings_Amount','Loan_Term']
[df.columns.get_loc(c) for c in cols if c in df]
```

Once you get all the indices for the columns you can simply use the below code to get the list of all column names

```
ColumnNames = list(df.columns.values)
featureSelectedColumnNames = []
 for indx,Cname in columnNames:
      if indx in AllFilteredIndexes:
           featureSelectedColumnNames.append(Cname)
           return Cname
```

You just return for all the indexes matching in the column names indexes with the filtered feature selected indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that, what you want:

```
[df.columns[i] for i in [3,45,67,89,101,145]]
```

In case you need that also for the index, it's the same principle:

```
df.index[1]
```

Or also, if you have multiple entries, for which you need the index values:

```
df.index[[3,45,67,89,101,145]]
```